# Django UNIQUE constraint failed when using signals

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-signals

UNIQUE constraint failed: brand_brand.slug.

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    log = models.ImageField(upload_to='brands')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = self.name.lower()
        return super(Brand, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Brand)
def create_brand_slug(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = slugify(instance.name)
```

```
class BrandForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = ['name', 'log']
```

I am saving the brand name in small letters in the database. When am tried to save the existing brand name in the capital letter, I Got UNIQUE constraint failed: brand_brand.slug error. When tried to save the exiting brand name with all in small letters, I got the proper error '**Brand with this Name already exists.'**

Comment: Add validation to the `name` field to ensure it's lowercase?

Comment: Instead of having that `self.name = self.name.lower()` in the models `save` method you need to do that in the forms `clean` etc. methods. The validation mostly happens _before_ calling `save`.